# Geodesic completeness in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, coordinate-systems, geodesics

There are well-known definitions of complete geodesic and [geodesically complete spacetime](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geodesic+completeness):

1. **A geodesic is complete** if an affine parameter for the geodesic extends to ±∞.
2. A spacetime is **geodesically complete** if all inextendible causal geodesics are complete.

For example, **Minkowski spacetime is geodesically complete**, as is the spacetime describing a static spherical star.

However, the **Kruskal spacetime** (extension of Schwarzschild spacetime) **is geodesically incomplete** because some geodesics have $r \to 0$ in finite affine parameter and hence cannot be extended to infinite affine parameter.

**Is this notion usefull in general relativity?**

**What is physical interpretation of geodesical completeness?**

**How are geodesically complete and incomplete spaces different in physical sence?**

**Is it possible to extend incomplete spacetime to geodesically complete?**

Edit: useful link [Light Rays, Singularities, and All That](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.03928)

Comment: Might be helpful https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/192834/does-geodesic-incompleteness-in-penrose-hawking-theorems-imply-curvature-blow-up?rq=1

Comment: "*A geodesic is complete if an affine parameter for the geodesic extends to $\pm\infty$*" - This is not necessarily true. A singularity may not be revealed by an affine parameter for some geodesics. As an illustration, consider $\rho=1/\varphi^n$ in polar coordinates. Here $\rho=0$ is a singularity, even if the affine parameter is unbound.

Answer (score 6):

> Is this notion usefull in general relativity?

Yes.

> What is physical interpretation of geodesical completeness?

Typically this means there is a singularity in the spacetime that prevents the geodesics from being continued, for example at the center of a black hole, or the Big Bang singularity. It could also mean there is some boundary to the spacetime, or there is some puncture (for example if you remove the point at the origin).

However the physical interpretation of a singularity itself is complicated. Most physicists believe that Nature does not have singularities, and the singularities in the classical solutions of GR are really a sign that GR is breaking down. So geodesic incompleteness may say more about the incompleteness of GR, than of spacetime.

> How are geodesically complete and incomplete spaces different in physical sence?

See above.

> Is it possible to extend incomplete spacetime to geodesically complete?

Not without changing the spacetime. For example, if the spacetime has a puncture you could "fill in" the puncture. But you wouldn't be able to extend the Scwarzschild solution in a way that avoids the singularity.

---

By the way, a note on terminology. You said:

> Kruskal spacetime (extension of Schwarzschild spacetime)

A more common usage of these words would be to say there is a black hole spacetime (the Schwarzschild solution), which can be described in Schwarzschild coordinates or Kruskal coordinates. The word "spacetime" should refer to the invariant geometry; what is different between Kruskal and Schwarzschild are the **coordinates**, not the spacetime itself.

Comment: Andrew, thank you. Could you give examples, how one can remove BH singularity with changing spacetime?

Comment: Oh I don't think you can remove the singularity in Scwarzschild. Like I said, "you wouldn't be able to extend the Scwarzschild solution in a way that avoids the singularity." Only in some circumstances could you "complete" geodesics. For example, if you had a spacetime that was flat spacetime with the origin removed, geodesics would end at the missing point, but you could complete the geodesics by filling in the missing point. However there is a real curvature singularity in Schwarzschild, there's no way to remove this.

Comment: Maybe one can connect  two spacetimes by Scwarzschild singularity? Is it possible?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. That's not to say that someone hasn't tried and made it work. But I am skeptical since joining two manifolds at a point is itself a singular construction. If you want to try this, you have to check that you are both satisfying Einstein's equations and that the geometry is smooth at the point where you are connecting the two spacetimes.

Comment: @Andrew I think the penrose-hawking singularity theorems forbid the extension of schwarzschild spacetime to remove signularity.

Comment: There you go! Thanks @Umaxo

Comment: @safesphere I fail to see relevance of any of the suggestions.  3D euclidean space is hardly a viable solution in GR, Declaring no interior sounds more like ignoring singularity rather than removing it and what is the difference between declaring no inner region and ending geodesics at the horizon?

Comment: @Umaxo "*I fail to see...*" - Too bad.

Comment: I'll just point out that I indirectly referenced the idea of excising the inner region in my answer via " It could also mean there is some boundary to the spacetime, or there is some puncture". Like I said in the answer, removing part of the spacetime by fiat also leads to geodesic incompleteness, since there are infalling geodesics that will hit the "firewall", instead of reaching the black hole interior (which is also what @Umaxo said in his comment).

Answer (score 3):

> Is this notion usefull in general relativity?

In GR, more useful than geodesic completness is geodesical maximality, which tells you that every geodesic either goes to infinite values of affine parameter or ends in singularity. That is due to the fact, that GR spacetimes can have singularities, so demanding geodesical completness is too restrictive.

However you want to to extend the manifold so that it is maximal. The spacetime where some geodesics would end at finite amount of affine parameter without arriving at singularity is quite a weird idea. Imagine taking a ship and traveling on one of this geodesics. This would mean that you would reach the end of the geodesics in finite amount of proper time. Then what? You cease to exist without any good reason?